# Git pull occasionally has issues pulling down in WSL2

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have been working inside a new git@stash repository that is cloned inside WSL2 and I am noticing occasional failures when pulling. I have properly setup my SSH keys and was able to clone down the repository with them. Sometimes I am able to pull, but other times I am met with the error below.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname stash: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't believe DNS is the issue because I can still ping bitbucket and other websites within WSL2, I have been able to clone and pull before, and I have no issues resolving hostnames when accessing web pages.

I have double checked the remote repository is set correctly with `git config -l` and have also tried to reset it to be sure with `git remote set-url origin <ssh://git@stash:my_server.git>`

I have also confirmed that the ssh keys are added to the ssh agent with `ssh-add -l` and I have confirmed the ssh service is running by executing the `service --status-all` command and seeing the `[ + ]` by the ssh service.

Does anyone know why I occasionally cannot seem to pull from the server within WSL2?

Any help is appreciated and thank you!

Comment: `Could not resolve hostname stash` This is a dns error; That isn’t a publicly resolvable host name - What is responsible for defining/resolving this host name?

Comment: In particular, what makes you think the unqualified name `stash` is correct in the first place? A fully qualified domain name (FQDN) tends to have the form `host.company.com` or `github.io` or the like, with at least one dot in it (and an implied final dot).

Comment: The name is correct because I have successfully cloned the repo and pulled before with this URL. However, occasionally I see this DNS related error. But as mentioned, the DNS settings on my device seem to be correct as I am not having other issues when it comes to resolving hostnames with commands like ```ping```.

Comment: If you `ping stash` Does that (ever) work? If it resolves, what does it resolve to and how/why? That’s the only host name relevant to your question. Asking another way, where did you clone from - is that your own server or a public service like bitbucket?

Comment: It seems there was a specific DNS server that I needed to point to that was additional to the one already specified within ```/etc/resolv.conf````. Since the server to access the repo is not publicly resolvable, I needed to include the proper DNS address that would allow me to resolve the hostname. @AD7six thank you for your help!